# Jenkins pipeline select git to use

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm using jenkins with pipeline job. My source code is cloned using

```
git(url: <----->,credentialsId: <----->,branch: <----->)
```

If I define more git in "Global Tool Configuration", how can I choose one of it? In a Freestyle project I have "Git executable" section where I can select it, but in Pipeline job not. Thanks.

Comment: tools {
            git 'toolversion' 
        }
this should take the git executable from tools.

Comment: Thanks for the info. And about MultiBranch Pipeline Project? Checkout of source code is done using GUI configuration before the pipeline starts.

Comment: If I get you correctly, You can specify tools execution in options itself

Comment: Ok Multibranch pipeline works well. So, I have a git on master and another git on slave. Both are configured from "Global Tools Configuration" and from Node configurations. But using a simple Pipeline project, first of all I do "tools { git 'my_slave ' }" and after "git(url: <----->,credentialsId: <----->,branch: <----->)"   From the log Jenkins seems to get right git version but when does git clone still use wrong git ( git of the master)